# How can I automatically add a class to a link based on active anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sidebar on the left, like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#anchor1">Anchor 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#anchor2">Anchor 2</a></li>
   ....
</ul>
```

And content on the right, like this:

```
<h1 class="anchor-elem" id="anchor1">Anchor 1</h1>
<h1 class="anchor-elem" id="anchor2">Anchor 2</h1>
```

Clicking on the sidebar links jumps to the anchor... no problem there. What I'm trying to achieve is to trap these anchors when they enter into the top scroll position, so that I can add a class to the appropriate LI element. I want to do this automatically, without having to specify each element.

For example, I found an answer to a question similar:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var section1Height = $('#section1').height();
    var section2Height = $('#section2').height();
    var section3Height = $('#section3').height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(winTop >= section1Height && winTop <= section2Height){
            $('#section1').addClass("newClass").not().removeClass("newClass");
        } else if(winTop >= section2Height && winTop <= section3Height){
            $('#section2').addClass("newClass").not().removeClass("newClass");
        } else if(winTop >= section3Height){
            $('#section3').addClass("newClass").not().removeClass("newClass");
        }
      });
    });
```

Pseudo Logic of what I want to achieve

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if .anchor-elem is in view ->
    find it's relative link on the menu and add class "active" to it
});
```

A similar example would be the bootstrap docs: http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.1.1/docs/getting-started/

I looked at their affix code but was quite confusing as it's interwoven with a ton of other functions.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? Without using bootstrap.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're already using jQuery, you could get the `.offset()` of each element and check to see if the window top is below that `.offset()`. DO NOT get the `offset()` on each scroll as it is a *very* expensive operation. I would recommend doing it on page load, if possible, saving the values to an array, and then checking the array. If you think the users will resize the window, which would affect the offsets, do it on load and on resize. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/qars0w0o/3/

Comment: This is great. Thank you. Only change I made was to loop through any anchor found within the menu and push them to the array automatically without identifying each one. Appreciate the help!